# How to raise error on image upload failure in Ajax Html Editor Extender?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

I am trying to upload image files using html editor extender. Everything works fine so far and I am able to save the file on `ImageUploadComplete` event. But I am not sure how to raise the error to UI and alert user if the image upload fails for some reason.

Your help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Update: We use MS enterprise library for exception handling. In normal postback errors, the exception gets logged first and would get redirected to the custom error page. The issues with using HTMLEditorExtender are:

1. redirect on error is NOT working
2. fileupload control is showing wrong upload status - "Uploaded" even in case of failures.

   Public Sub HTMLEditor_ImageUploadComplete(sender As Object,
                         e As AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs) 
                         Handles HTMLEditor.ImageUploadComplete

   HTMLEditor.AjaxFileUpload.SaveAs("D:\Uploads\" + Path.GetFileName(e.FileName))

   End Sub

Comment: Do you want to do it via code-behind or client side?  And could you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: I am able to catch the error in code behind using try catch block, but the issue is I am not able to redirect to the error page or show the correct status in the file upload control. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a server-side control you should be able to report errors like you would server-side for anything else (i.e. ASP.NET Label control with red forecolor and invisible until an error occurs), like this:

```
<asp:Label id="ErrorLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False"/>
```

Then on the method referenced in your `OnImageUploadComplete` attribute of the extender control you can direct error information to this error label control.

Comment: I tried using the label control and changing the control text/visibility on error. Unfortunately none of the changes gets  displayed on the UI, since the editor is an ajax control and there is no page refresh on error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply throw an exception and it will show as failed upload in the `AjaxFileUpload` box used by the `HtmlEditorExtender`.

If you want to handle the error yourself, you would either need to use the `OnClientUploadError` client side event of the `AjaxFileUpload` or download the `AjaxControlToolkit` source code and edit it to work as you need.

If your environment is unable to respond with and error HTTP Status then you can manually respond using `Context.Response.Write()` and write the appropriate JSON that the `AjaxFileUpload` expects. And then handle its client side events accordingly.